# Testing Style on React component

Tags: css, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I have the following class with a function, that opens a modal (`open_modal(...)`) in a separate file to a component as I have a large number of modals that use this functionality.

```
import open from "open";
import $    from "jquery";

class ReactHelpers {

    static open_webpage(page_url) {
        open(page_url);
    }

    static open_modal(overlay_id, modal_id) {
        $(overlay_id).css("display", "block");
        $(modal_id).css("display", "block");
    }

    static close_modal(overlay_id, modal_id) {
        $(overlay_id).css("display", "none");
        $(modal_id).css("display", "none");
    }
}

export default ReactHelpers;
```

I am trying to assert that the open_modal function has added css to the divs in question as below:

```
    it('should close the modal', function () {
        const wrapper = shallow(
            <div id="overlay_id">
                <div id="modal_id">
                    <p>modal</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
        const overlay = wrapper.find('#overlay_id')
        const modal = wrapper.find('#modal_id')
        ReactHelpers.open_modal(overlay, modal);
        console.log('OVERLAY ', overlay);
        expect(overlay.prop('style')).toHaveProperty('display', 'block');
        expect(modal_style).toHaveProperty('display', 'block');
    });
```

Further, I'm sure to how the open_webpage function would be tested as this is a library function. In my other tests in my other components, I'm mocking this so it's never actually been tested.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test style of dom elements:

1. You should mount the component (using `mount`), instead of just creating it (using `shallow`).
2. Since you're changing the style of dom element directly, You should test the style of the dom element (`component.getDOMNode().style.display`), instead of testing the react style property (`component.prop.style`).

example:

```
import $ from "jquery";
it("should create a div and changes its color to red", () => {
  const wrap = mount(
      <div id="red_el"></div>
  );
  const el = wrap.find("#red_el").getDOMNode()
  $(el).css("color", "red");
  expect(el.style.color).toEqual("red");
});
```

In your case:

```
it("should open modal", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <div>
      <div id="overlay" style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <div id="modal" style={{ display: "none" }}>
          overlay
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  const overlay = wrapper.find("#overlay").getDOMNode();
  const modal = wrapper.find("#modal").getDOMNode();
  ReactHelpers.open_modal(overlay, modal);
  expect(overlay.style.display).toEqual("block");
  expect(modal.style.display).toEqual("block");
});
```

[See it live on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-answer-react-test-tgk8l?file=/src/ReactHelpers.test.js) (switch to the tests tab to run the tests .)

Comment: Hi yaya, Thank you so very much for your response. This worked for me! I see where I went wrong and I'll learn from my mistakes :).  

I don't suppose you know what kind of approach I could take with open_webpage? is it the case to just make a mock function for ````open````

Comment: @OrangeSubmarine121 No problem. Actually two separate problems are best to be asked in separate questions, so please put that on another question. but to answer it: if it was a simple library function like: `add`, you could just call it and check if it works currently. but since it opens a webpage, that's hard to test it. and i don't think that mocking works either, cause it just does one simple task (opening a webpage), and if you mock it, you can't actually test it. so in my opinion the test doesn't make sence it this case, unless you can check if `window.open` is being called or ...

Comment: Awesome no worries it makes sense to ask them as two separate questions. Thanks for the advice!